# Splitting a collection of maps depending on a map values in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to set up a system that will print a certain amount of pages depending on the amount of items supplied and how many lines that have.

I basically have a list of maps with a couple of fields, including a name field that could be quite long and span over a number of lines on the printer. I have a function that can discern how many lines it will take up, so that's no issue.

The main problem is that I want to split (well, partition, if you use clojure's terminology) the collection of products when it gets to 30 lines, so I can start another page. Is there a way to run over the collection working out the total lines up to 30 (less if there is a multi-line product that would otherwise go over 30 lines) and then split it?

I'd like to turn this

```
[{:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
 {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
 {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
 {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
 {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}
 {:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}
 {:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
 {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
 {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
 {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
 {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}
 {:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}
 {:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
 {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
 {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
 {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
 {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}
 {:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}]
```

into this

```
[[{:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
  {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
  {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
  {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
  {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}
  {:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}
  {:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
  {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
  {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
  {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
  {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}]
 [{:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}
  {:qty 2 :size "M" :product "Testing 1 2 3"}
  {:qty 1 :size "S" :product "Hello there world"}
  {:qty 12 :size "XS" :product "Some really long product name just to test"}
  {:qty 932 :size "L" :product "More longer names to play with"}
  {:qty 1 :size "M" :product "Another product name"}
  {:qty 1242 :size "XS" :product "This is just an obscenely long product name that I am hoping will spill over on to the next lines"}]]
```

The max line-length for the product name is 25 characters

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: I think an example would be useful.

Comment: you mean something like (partition-by how-many-lines coll) ?

Comment: sounds more complicated than that, because the coll has the number of lines in each element, so it's not just give me n items. it's count the lines in each item, give me enough items to fill how-many-lines.

Comment: Example was added. The example above is 52 lines long (including an extra blank line between each item), so I would need 2 pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to give you an answer to a similar problem, and you should be able to extrapolate from there to get the answer to your problem.

---

### Question:

How do I group a sequence of strings into subgroups of adjacent strings with a total of at most *n* characters in each subgroup?

### Solution:

```
;; Data
(def input
  ["asdjasjdklasj" "dkjfsj" "dfkjsj" "kfjskd" "skdjfsjkdjdfs"
   "dfjskd" "wiuennsdw" "dskjdfsdjwed" "wiuf" "mncxnejs" "fjsjd"
   "dkjsf" "djsk" "djf" "erjfdkjcxzasd" "sjkja"])

;; Counting function
(def char-count count)

;; Partition function
(defn group-to-size [size coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (loop [[x & xs' :as xs] coll, n 0, acc []]
      (if (nil? x) (cons acc nil)
        (let [n' (+ n (char-count x))]
          (if (<= n' size)
            (recur xs' n' (conj acc x))
            (cons acc (group-to-size size xs))))))))

;; Sample grouping by 15 characters
(group-to-size 15 input)

; => (["asdjasjdklasj"]
;     ["dkjfsj" "dfkjsj"]
;     ["kfjskd"]
;     ["skdjfsjkdjdfs"]
;     ["dfjskd" "wiuennsdw"]
;     ["dskjdfsdjwed"]
;     ["wiuf" "mncxnejs"]
;     ["fjsjd" "dkjsf" "djsk"]
;     ["djf"]
;     ["erjfdkjcxzasd"]
;     ["sjkja"])

;; Resulting character counts per group for the above sample
(->> (group-to-size 15 input)
     (map (comp count (partial apply concat))))

; => (13 12 6 13 15 12 12 14 3 13 5)
```

---

Instead of counting characters in a string you want to count lines in a product description.  Your function for counting the number of lines per product is the equivalent of `char-count` in my code above. I think you should be able to figure it out from here.

**Note:** This solution has the added benefit of being *lazy*. That means it doesn't bother partitioning the entire set of strings if you end up only wanting to use the first partition. In your case, it would translating into not partitioning the entire inventory if the user decides to only view the first couple pages.

Comment: Will it stack overflow given enough input--it looks like it does non-tail recursion? (I could be wrong here, just asking...)

Comment: @WesFreeman - Nope! It uses tail calls within the `loop` construct, so there's no problem there, and then the [`lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) wrapping the body of `group-to-size` ensures that each successive element is computed lazily. You can try it yourself on an infinite input, e.g.:  `(take 5 (group-to-size 15 (repeat "a")))`.

Comment: But the loop calls the function itself, as well as recur.

Comment: @WesFreeman - The `recur` is bound to the `loop`, not to the function. The tail recursion has two base cases: 1) if `x` is `nil` we return `nil`, thus ending the lazy sequence, and 2) if we've exceeded the character quota then it returns the accumulator `acc` as the next item in the lazy sequence. Notice that the _entire function body_ is wrapped in `lazy-seq`. That's what keeps it from causing a stack overflow. You might want to read the [documentation for `lazy-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq) if you're not clear on how it works.

Comment: I've tested it, and it definitely works. To (take 1000000 ...). I missed that the recursive call only happens when n is greater than size. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @WesFreeman - It will work past 1 million if you don't try to keep the entire result. I just ran it with 10 million, but I only keep the last element (and it took over a minute to complete): `(last (take 10000000 (group-to-size 15 (repeat "a"))))`

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it stopped working--just meant that was as far as I bothered to test. :)

Comment: Thanks heaps @DaoWen! I seem to be having an issue where it will just stop running after the first set of items under the limit. All I really changed was running my line count function on `(x :product)`. Do you have any idea what would cause that? Also, a laxy list was a bit overkill :P I'll only be doing this on about 50 items at the absolute max.

Comment: @TomBrunoli - Sorry, there was a bug that caused the last set to be thrown away! I changed `(if (nil? x) nil` to `(if (nil? x) (cons acc nil)`. Does that work?